# representing Double values in Katai

Tags: double, kaitai-struct

Some of the values I need to read in my ksy file are double's which I assume is a binary64 structure. The native data-types for a float won't stretch that far. Has anyone managed to represent this datatype in Kaitai ?

Answer (score 0):

"binary64" is a normal [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) double-precision floats, occupying 64 bits = 8 bytes.

They're perfectly supported by vast majority of languages and, subsequently, Kaitai Struct offers built-in supports for them as `type: f8` (float, 8 bytes long).

If you're rather interested in larger floating point values (binary128, binary256 — i.e. quad or octuple precision), there is no built-in support for them in KS due to lack of standard support for these types in most target languages. If you want something like that, the recommended way would be implementing one as [opaque type](http://doc.kaitai.io/user_guide.html#opaque-types) in a target language of your choice. That will likely require you to bringing in some external library which implements this type using some kind of software emulation / complex arithmetics — as [hardware support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Hardware_support) seems to be almost non-existent in commodity CPUs (like Intel or ARM) as of 2020.

For more details on these, see [issue #101](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct/issues/101).